# What do you call the standing ads outside of a store?

Tags: word-request

You have the store sign, which is usually hanging outside of the store. Then you have the billboards, which are bigger and are held high with metal support.

What do you call the store ads that are standing? Usually, outside of a store?

Comment: Please add a picture so that we know exactly what you're referring to.

Comment: @RonJohn I was thinking of that, but then found out I didn't know what to type on Google.

Comment: pictures of the front of an (urban?) restaurant might have them.  You could highlight the sign(s) you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sandwich Boards](https://www.topnotchsigns.co.uk/?page=Wearable%20Signs) are generally worn by people standing or walking around outside stores (referring to the person wearing them as the filling in a [sandwich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich)), although the name can refer to floor standing signs **normally** called [A-Boards](https://www.instantprint.co.uk/a-frames-and-boards).  Other signage which stands on the ground can either be [Swing Boards](https://www.creative-solutions-direct.co.uk/shop/category/swing-boards) or [Forecourt Signs](https://www.creative-solutions-direct.co.uk/shop/category/forecourt-signs-changeable-graphics).  All types of floor standing sign can [generically](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/generically) be called *forecourt signs* or *pavement signs*.

All these signs can have changeable graphics or permanent graphics.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are talking about a [Sandwich Board](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandwich_board)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking about self-standing banner which doesn't need any support or it also called as [Roller banner](https://www.solopress.com/blog/tutorials/a-guide-to-roller-banners/)

Comment: Since this is a site for English Language Learners, please take the time to ensure your spelling and grammar is correct. Lead by example. Welcome to the site!